# Calling a tuple inside a list

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I need to call upon a specific element of a tuple inside a list of tuples for example

```
list = [(tuple1 ,10,10), (tuple2 ,20,20), (tuple3 ,30,30)]
```

how do i go about calling upon a specific element in one of the tuples

EDIT:

so my program is used to take a file that has a list of numbers representing tiles for a game level. So I get it to take the numbers and put a value for what tile they will be and it calculates there x and y position into a tuple of the format (tileType, x, y). I need to call the tileType to check what tile it is then need to call the x and y elements to place it in the correct position

Comment: Avoid using built-in names as name of variables. In your case replace `list` with something else(like `sequence`, `list_of_tuples` etc). Failing to do so *will* eventually produce bugs in your code, since the variables will override built-in names and change the behaviour of your program in unexpected ways.

Comment: i used that name just as an example dont worry i have it changed in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just index using square brackets:

```
In [2]: l = [('tuple1' ,10,10), ('tuple2' ,20,20), ('tuple3' ,30,30)]

In [3]: l[0][0]
Out[3]: 'tuple1'

In [4]: l[0][1]
Out[4]: 10

In [5]: l[0][2]
Out[5]: 10

In [6]: l[1][0]
Out[6]: 'tuple2'
```

and so on.

If that's not what you're after, please clarify the question.

Answer (score -1):

Is this helpful ?

```
[some_function(item[0]) for item in list]
```

The above code applies `some_function` on every first element of the tuple inside the list. It is a list comprehension: [Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)